# How to encrypt all apache files php output in Ubuntu 18 with AES 128 Encryption?

Tags: apache, ssl

I have seen an Apache server which I can't find its programmer that he implemented some kind of AES encryption in all PHP script files hosted in Apache. Where when client requests the link using HTTP it outputs the PHP script array output with no encryption and completely readable but when client requests the link using HTTPS, the output is encrypted with AES encryption.

For Example, when client request this link http://example.com/activate.php?login=2571397584808022
the output looks like that in the browser

```
{"authentification":[{"status":"001","msg":"Welcome, your account expire after 274 days"}]}
```

But when the client requests the link with HTTPS like that https://example.com/activate.php?login=2571397584808022
The PHP script output looks like that

```
m6TDiNpa3ey/pmppthFnVb0CYoL4ae52PnYrAbGnwiCwlYnpqeJVcoRBNvcW1lpPbkOqcmxX/9QuiawzDFjGLGCFroWnp1oQ/H5E7uLjL+ghSRKFM5JApCnEUV3LzC4d
```

I can confirm that it is AES 128 encryption. First, I thought that it was some more codes added to this specific PHP script (`activate`) to encrypt the output but I noticed that this feature happens in all PHP scripts and files in all Apache server directories if the client request was HTTPS not HTTP. I think it is more of a configuration is SSL Apache config. I am asking if anyone is familiar with this kind of configurations for Apache or give me a hint to start with.

Comment: If it is in Apache, find the VirtualHost that defines how to listen on port 443.  In there, you will see all the configuration directives that apply.  If you do not find what you are looking for, post this configuration here, users here will help.

Comment: "I think it is more of a configuration is SSL Apache config." It is not TLS (SSL died 20 years ago) that does what you see, as the content is seen unencrypted by the browser at the end. TLS just allows to transparently encrypt/decrypt the content between server and browser.